# How do you execute a SnowFlake Stored Procedure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a Snowflake connection via Power BI Desktop after providing the Server and Warehouse Name; then under Advanced Options I specified the Database and entered the following in the SQL statement text area:

call myStoredProcedureName();

and received a pop-up stating "Unable to connect. We encountered an error while trying to connect. Details: 'Native queries aren't supported by this value'".

This is using Snowflake type connection so what am I missing? If I execute using the same syntax directly in Snowflake, I get the results without any issues.

Forgot to mention that I'm using Import mode, b/c my 1st attempt using Direct mode produced an error clearly stating Direct Mode wasn't supported.

Comment: Found something similar [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/quot-Native-queries-aren-t-supported-by-this-value-quot-When/m-p/2225980)

Comment: You're using PowerBI Desktop - which driver are you using?  You can use the Snowflake ODBC driver and call the stored proc in the SQL statement.  I assume the stored proc is returning a tabular result set, correct?

Comment: See comment from @pankaj above - there's the answer in the thread of the post he references.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same conclusion that direct mode does not work, but import seemed to work fine after setting EnableFolding=false

```
let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(
            Snowflake.Databases(
                URL,
                WH,
                [Role=ROLE]
            ){[Name=DB]}[Data], 
            "call schema.my_proc();",
            null, 
            [EnableFolding=false] // set this to false!
    )
in
    Source
```

Found the solution buried [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/quot-Native-queries-aren-t-supported-by-this-value-quot-When/m-p/2225980).